# Why zero is not taken into account to calculate in OR condition and is taken into account to calculate in AND condtion?

Tags: javascript

Why not zero - which is not a boolean - but a number?

Suppose this example:

```
var current = 0;
current += Number(3) || Number(4); // now current is 0 + 3 = 3

var current = 0;
current += Number(-3) || Number(4); // now current is 0 + -3 = -3

var current = 0;
current += Number(0) || Number(4); // now current is 0 + 4 = 4
```

So, in my example it's taking the value to be added which number is not zero.

So, my question is why actually the OR operator `||` is only taking the value to calculate is rather than zero?

And also,

```
var current = 0;
current += Number(0) && Number(3); // now current is 0

var current = 0;
current += Number(3) && Number(5); //now current is 5
```

I'm really confused how the AND and OR operators are working here with the number types (not a Boolean).

Answer (score 3):

Logical operators evaluate both the left and right expressions (if necessary). They both short-circuit immediately. It means that, if the first expression itself is enough to produce the result, irrespective of the other expression, then the other expression will not be evaluated at all. For example, in OR operator, if the first expression is Truthy, then we don't have to evaluate the other expression, the same way, in AND operator, if the first expression is Falsy, we don't have to evaluate the other expression.

Now, we are talking about Truthy and Falsy, right? What are they? When we evaluate an expression, the Truthiness is determined by the following table as per [ECMA 5.1 Standard specification](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2),

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Argument Type | Result                                                |
|:--------------|------------------------------------------------------:|
| Undefined     | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Null          | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion). |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Number        | The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN;|
|               | otherwise the result is true.                         |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| String        | The result is false if the argument is the empty      |
|               | String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is  |
|               | true.                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Object        | true                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, unless the number is `+0`, `-0` or `NaN`, it will be considered Truthy. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log(Boolean(0));
# false
console.log(Boolean(-1));
# true
console.log(Boolean(100));
# true
```

That is why OR operator takes the value of the non-zero number.

Quoting from the [ECMA 5.1 Specifications for OR Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11),

> ```
> LogicalANDExpression :
>     BitwiseORExpression
>     LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression
>
> LogicalORExpression :
>     LogicalANDExpression
>     LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression
> ```
>
> The production *LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression &&
>   BitwiseORExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be *GetValue(lref)*.
> 3. If *ToBoolean(lval)* is false, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> 5. Return *GetValue(rref)*.
>
> The production *LogicalORExpression : LogicalORExpression ||
>   LogicalANDExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalORExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be *GetValue(lref)*.
> 3. If *ToBoolean(lval)* is *true*, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 5. Return *GetValue(rref)*.
>
> **NOTE** **The value produced by a `&&` or `||` operator is not necessarily of type `Boolean`. The value produced will always be the
>   value of one of the two operand expressions.**

Comment: Clearly the more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The value of an OR statement is determined the moment you encounter "true" (something other than zero.. 'truthy'). Until you encounter that, you need to keep going: maybe one of the other terms is true?

This explains the behavior you are seeing.

```
current += Number(3) || Number(4)        - 3 is true, condition met, no need to look at next term

current += Number(0) || Number(4)        - 0 is false, keep going, 4 is true, condition met
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values;
>   when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I think zero is set to be falsy condtion and all others are set to be truthy condition while we use AND or OR operator for Number.

Consider the following what value does it take to calculate:

Remember 0 is false and all other values (including negative values) are true while we take number.
Also, suppose the followings are the numbers not the booleans.

```
5 || 0 // true || false returns true, so takes 5
0 || 3 // false || true returns true, so takes 3
4 && 0 // true && false returns false, so takes 0
0 && 6 // false && true returns false, so takes 0
2 && 3 // true && true returns true, which value would take???? 
      // Ummm, last defined value, huh i.e. 3
```